# Using emitter follower as voltage source

Tags: transistors, led, voltage-regulator, led-driver, voltage-source

I have an open-drain IC and I need to connect it to another device, avr, which is 3.3V, additionally information leds are needed. Avr should read digital signal from that open-drain device. Avr is powered from a weak LDO (10mA), so it's bad idea to connect leds directly to it. Input voltage is 5V.

Could I use the next schematic ? What are possible problems?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5lKph.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The LEDs will need series current limiting resistors, otherwise they will very likely burn out (or overheat the transistor when they draw too much current). The signals going to the AVR should be taken from the LED's cathode, not directly from the emitter of the transistor (this is 3V all the time, after all).

You might also need some large-value resistors in parallel to the LEDs to pull the signal high all the way so the AVR properly recognizes it. And a capacitor from Q1's base to ground might help with the stability of the output voltage.

In any case, the voltage regulator you've built with that voltage divider and transistor is perfectly fine. Keep in mind that the voltage divider will consume some current all the time.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Why are current limiting resistors needed? If choose leds with  3.3v forward voltage, wont they consume only their forward current? Any divider may be choosed for any fv..

Comment: @DenisJelesniak:  LEDs are current operated devices.  You have to provide a fixed current to them.  Once they start conducting (for your 3.3V LEDs, that's somewhere a little above 3.0V) they act like a short circuit.  If you don't limit the current, they will try to pass **all** the current your power supply can supply.    Either the transistors will burn out, or the LEDs.  In either case, it is not good.

Comment: NOBODY makes a 3.3V LED. LEDs have a range of forward voltages, some are 3.0V and some are 3.6V. Look at its datasheet. Also the forward voltage changes when the LED heats up. An LED is powered with a current, never with a voltage.

Comment: I can make any forward voltage with this divider. But I’m not sure that led can try to take all the current. I still suppose that it works according figure in datasheet.. e.g 20 mA on 2.8V

Comment: @DenisJelesniak Look at the graph of forward voltage vs. current of your LED (or any other diode). It's a very steep curve - in fact, it's exponential. Even the tiniest change in voltage causes a huge change in current. At the same time, the diode's forward voltage goes down as temperature goes up, so it'll draw even more current as it warms up - thermal runaway. Look at the graph for current vs. forward voltage of this diode's datasheet, you can clearly see that the current goes up as the temperature increases: https://diotec.com/tl_files/diotec/files/pdf/datasheets/1n4001.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Your circuit won't work the way you think it does.

R1 and R2 together with Q1 will put out approximately 3.3V at the emitter of Q1.  So far, so good.

The rest is not so good.

If you close SW1 then D1 will be connected to 3.3V with nothing to limit the current.  LEDs are not just fancy lights.  They are diodes.  When they are supplied with a voltage above their forward voltage, they become the next best thing to a short circuit.  D1 will try to draw all of the current that your 5V source can supply.  Either it will burn out, or the transistor will burn out.  Since you say SW1 and SW2 are actually open drain outputs from another device, you run a risk of destroying that device as well.

Any time you use an LED, you need to control the current it receives.  This is typically done with a resistor, though you may see constant current sources used as well.

The next problem is that as you have drawn the circuit, the outputs going to the AVR will never be less than 3.3V - no matter what SW1 and SW2 do.  You mention using 3.3V LEDs.  If you connect the LED to ground through one of the switches, then the output will only ever "see" the 3.3V provided by your emitter follower.  The only way the AVR will ever see a low signal is when some part of your emitter follower/LED circuit burns out.

You'll need to do something more like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff5UIj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

AVR1 and AVR2 will receive the input from your open drain signals.  When the open drains are open, the AVR will see a high.  When the open drains are pulled down, the AVR will see a low.

Q2 and Q3 are to drive the LEDs.  They convert the high/low signal from the AVR outputs to an on/off for the LEDs.

R7 and R8 are to limit the base current through transistors Q2 and Q3.  With R3 and R4, R7 and R8 make voltage dividers - your AVR signals will have about 3V as a high rather than 3.3V.  That should still be enough for the AVR to correctly recognize high and low.

R5 and R6 are there to limit the current through the LEDs.  The value of 100 ohms should allow a little less than 20 milliamperes to each LED (assuming a 3.3V forward voltage for the LEDs.)  You will probably find them to be terribly bright at 20 milliamperes - just use a large resistor value.  I'd probably try 1k ohm instead of 100 ohms.  That's 2 milliamperes to the LEDs, and from my experience still awful bright with blue LEDs.

The LEDs will light when the open drain signals are high and they will be dark when the open drain signals pull down.

That's more complicated than your circuit, but it will work without destroying parts.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-use-led-without-resistor-and-not-burn

I still suppose that led will work fine if voltage fits them. I can tune divider for their forward voltage and put  relatively small limiting resistor in the collector. And add pullup resistors for avr outputs ( and move them to anodes)

Comment: @DenisJelesniak:  That Quora "answer" is wrong.  Follow it and you'll burn out your LEDs.  That was written by someone who has never connected LEDs.

Comment: But, hey, they're your LEDs.  Who am I to stop you from destroying them.